# Can i persist abstract class in database using Doctrine2 and symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, abstract-class, persist

I have this class structure

`UserInterface` --- `abstract Class User extends UserInterface`

`class Teacher extends  User`

Now i am using class Table inheritance

so in dtabase i have two tables `User` and `Teacher with FK to User`

I am persisting abstract class like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="xxxx\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"puser" = "User", "teacher" = "Teacher"})
 */
abstract class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
```

I want to know that am i doing right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Abstract class can not be initiated you can not persist it with Doctrine. You can persist classes which extends the Abstract class which in this case is Teacher.

Comment: But it is working fine. This bundle also uses the same thing  https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: you cannot do `new AbstractClass()` in PHP that is impossible. And in your case you can not do `new User()`